# LINQ queries in a loop checking for null conditions and looking for cleaner way to write this code

Tags: c#, linq

I have code looping over data in a JSON file and so based on conditions of wildcard for the first, OR Second OR Third variable  , I was doing the regex, then writing it out and I really don't like the way it looks.

So readability is important and performance,  but data integrity and error handling etc.. are as well

What is a better way to write this?

```
for loop.... 

     var firstWildCard = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.ExternalPolicy, $"^.*{Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}{Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)}$")).FirstOrDefault()?.PackageID;
     if(firstWildCard == null)
     {
         var secondWildCard = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.ExternalPolicy, $"^{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}.*{Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)}$")).FirstOrDefault()?.PackageID;
             if(secondWildCard == null)
             {
                 var thirdWildCard = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.ExternalPolicy, $"^{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}{Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}.*$")).FirstOrDefault()?.PackageID;

             }
     }
```

Comment: Refactor with a method/lambda having the duplicated code by passing some parameters if needed.

Comment: Can you show me an example?  @OlivierRogier

Comment: Does the @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu match your goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

```
var patterns = new string[]{
  $"^.*{Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}{Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)}$",
  $"^{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}.*{Regex.Escape(hccCpmtFctrCd)}$",
  $"^{Regex.Escape(hcdpPlnCvgCD)}{Regex.Escape(HcdpPmtFctrCd)}.*$"
}

var wildcards = new List<String>();

foreach (var pattern in patterns)
{
    var matchResult = vidaBiliy.SponsorPackage.Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s.ExternalPolicy, pattern)).FirstOrDefault()?.PackageID;
    wildcards.Add(matchResult);
    
    if (matchResult != null) 
        break;
}
```